The length of a one-turn helix on a Horn Torus
The length of a one-turn helix on a unit Horn Torus (corresponding to a torus of $r=R=1$) can be computed from integrating the differential length element:
$ds = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2} \, dt
$,
where $x(t)$, $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ can be obtained from the parametric equations of the helix on a horn torus:
$x(t) = (R + r \cos t) \cos t$
$y(t) = (R + r \cos t) \sin t $
$z(t) = r \sin t$
If we use this python program:
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def integrand(t, R, r):
    dxdt = - (R + r * np.cos(t)) * np.sin(t) - r * np.sin(t) * np.cos(t)
    dydt = (R + r * np.cos(t)) * np.cos(t) - r * np.sin(t)**2
    dzdt = r * np.cos(t)
    
    return np.sqrt(dxdt**2 + dydt**2 + dzdt**2)

# Parameters
R = 1  # Major radius
r = 1  # Minor radius

# Compute the integral
result, error = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, 2 * np.pi, args=(R, r))

print(f"The length of the helical path is approximately: {result}")


We find the result is 9.507587683092.... Is there a closed-form expression for this length?
Edit:
Note that the integral can be simplified as
$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^2 +R^2+2rR\cos(t) +r^2 \cos^2(t)} dt$
and for $r=R=1$ it becomes
$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2+2 \cos(t) + \cos^2(t)} dt$
which can be simplified further to:
$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+ 4\cos^4(t/2)}dt $


By perioidicity we may as well consider
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sqrt{2 + 2 \cos t + \cos^2 t}\,dt .$$
Changing variable via the tangent half-angle substitution,
$$t = 2 \arctan u, \qquad dt = \frac{2 \,du}{1 + u^2},$$
transforms the integral to
$$2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{u^4 + 2 u^2 + 5}}{(1 + u^2)^2} \,du .$$
The presence of the square root of a quartic suggests that elliptic integral functions might be necessary to express the integral, and that appears to be the case here. A standard algorithm lets you rewrite the integrand in terms of standard complete elliptic integral functions, but consulting a CAS suggests that the process is a mess. After some coaxing, Maple yields
$$\boxed{4 \cdot 5^{1/4} (E \left(\beta\right) - K \left(\beta\right)) + \frac{2 (3 + \sqrt 5)}{5^{1/4}} \Pi (\alpha, \beta)} ,$$
where
$$\alpha := \frac12 - \frac{3\sqrt5}{10} \quad \textrm{and} \quad \beta := \sqrt{\frac2{5 + \sqrt5}} ,$$ and where $K, E, \Pi$ are the complete elliptic integral functions of the first, second, and third kinds, respectively. The result does not look appreciably better than for general values of $R, r$. The numerical value of the expression is
$$9.50758768322\ldots ,$$
which agrees closely with the numerical value produced by the Python program in the question statement.

I tried to compute this expression with Python, but it gives me a different answer, 8.8333..... Here is the code
https://www.online-python.com/AIlVG8Bwua

It looks like this difference is a consequence of differing conventions for the complete elliptic integral functions in the mpmath package (https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/elliptic.html, n.b. the comment in the entry for the ellipk function, "Note that the argument is the parameter $m = k^2$, not the modulus $k$ which is sometimes used.") and in Maple (https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=EllipticF).
Replacing each instance of $\beta$ with $\beta^2$ in your code and executing yields for me: Result: 9.5075876830923831161827602384828837746573244191573.

Notice that $\beta^2 = \frac12 - \frac{\sqrt5}{10} = \frac13(1 + \alpha)$.

Computing your formula and the numerical integral using mpmath with the same precision gives an agreement up to 16 digits only. So, it seems like a good fit, not an exact answer. You can check the code here https://www.online-python.com/QH9T8mMRUu

I don't see the same issue when I run the code in Sage Cell: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=xnitum The values appear to agree to high precision with each other and with the values produced by Maple for both the numerical integration and the exact value given in my answer.

Replacing the exponent (1/4) in my code (running on Jupyter) with mp.mpf(1)/4 fixes the precision of computing your formula and gives the exact result as the numerical integral.  So, I take the formula as an exact answer.
This length is analogous to a circumference of a sphere. The question is why such a simple shape that has an area of $4 \pi ^2$ does have a perimeter that is a such a mathematical beast! I was expecting some simple formula in terms of $\pi^2$!

Heavy apologies... after finding the error and delay in posting  :(

Reading about the elliptic integral functions, you seem to have replaced one integral with a few other integrals! I could have also called the integral in the question a new function and expressed the length in terms of this 'function'!

You could have, and that's how many functions are defined in the first place: the error function, the exponential integral, the logarithmic integral, etc. Many authors even define $\log x := \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$, which is arguably the most convenient definition. Typical values of elliptic integral functions cannot be expressed in closed form in terms of elementary functions, so probably there isn't such an expression for the arc length in this question. Incidentally, $K, E$ are expressible in terms of the hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1$, but $\Pi$ is not.
